# Actors compete in tournaments

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

- There are 3 tournaments organised for actors.
- In each tournament, four actors can enter.
- In each match, two actors can play.
- In the first round, there are two matches.
- The second round is the final where the winners of the first round face off.

---

**Tournament 1**

[image]

---

**Tournament 2**

[image]

---

**Tournament 3**

[image]

---

***Who are the winners of these 3 tournaments based on the results of the first rounds?***

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The winner of the first tournament is

> [image]

The winner of the second tournament is

> [image]

The winner of the third tournament is

> [image]

Because this is a game of

> Rock, Paper, Scissor where each celebrity has a surname starting with the first two letters of one of the three

Comment: Nicely decoded! Rot13(Vg vf svefg gjb yrggref bs rnpu fheanzr ol gur jnl) :)

Comment: Just noticed it :) I'll edit